# Diminished effects in final rendered Adobe Premiere Pro CC video

Tags: video, premiere, adobe

I'm using the ProcAmp effect to significantly boost the contrast in my video project (I have multiple ProcAmp effects layered on the same clip). In the preview in Premiere, as I'm working on it, it looks great. But when I view the final rendered version, the contrast isn't carrying over.

Is this because of the layered effects? Or inappropriate export settings? Or something else?

Comment: Show a screenshot of your preview and same frame in export video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you layering the ProcAmp Filter onto the same clip?

It's possible theres a bug with that... there are bugs.

You could try taking your base clip and putting it on a sequence. Add your ProcAmp.

Then right click the sequence in your Project window -> Create New Sequence from Clip.

Now you have a nested sequence of your original.

Try applying the ProcAmp then to that "clip" which is actually a nested sequence.

The results should appear the same, but you wont be applying the proc-amp to the same clip, rather, each nested sequence will have its own.

You can repeat and re-nest etc.

Secondly, you might just be better doing the effect in after effects, and using dynamic link to bridge the clip in. It acts much the same way but will add render time.

Answer (score 0):

In my first encounters with Premiere, I ran into the problem that there are many ways to render clips, and only one correct way, which is to render the sequence containing the clip (and its effects), not the clip itself.  It is quite easy to have the clip, not the sequence, selected, hit Media Export and have it encode the wrong thing.  Make sure you have the sequence selected, and export *that*.  I do this by selecting the sequence, right clicking the selected sequence, and choosing Export from there.